# Better way to write multiple switch cases in multiple foreach methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm trying to make a web app where people can add exercises to a routine for a certain day of the week, and it'll show their entire routine on one page. I also want the names of the exercises to link to their corresponding page. So for example, my data looks like this in mongodb:

```
_id:60e2edf7014df85fd8b6e073
routineName:"test"
routineUsername: "tester"
monday:[{
    _id: 60e430d45395d73bf41c7be8
    exercise: "Bicep curls"
}{
    _id: 60e4329592e3fa445836d983
    exercise: "Overhead press"
}]
tuesday:[{
    _id:60e2ee8962c0c15840ecc69b
    exercise:"Hanging leg raise"
}] 
..etc
```

I have this in EJS:

```
<% routine.monday.forEach(monday => { %>
    <ul>
    <% switch (monday.exercise) {
        case 'Hanging leg raise' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/abs/hanginglegraise"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;
            
        case 'Bicep curls' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/biceps/bicepcurls"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;
            
        case 'Calf raises' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/calves/calfraises"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;

        case 'Barbell bench press' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/chest/barbellbenchpress"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;

        case 'Incline bench press' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/chest/inclinebenchpress"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;

        case 'Overhead press' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/frontdeltoids/overheadpress"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;

        case 'Barbell squat' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/quadriceps/barbellsquat"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;

        case 'Shrugs' : %>
        <a href="/muscles/trapezius/shrugs"><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
                <% break;
    } %>
    </ul>
<% }) %>
..etc
```

But as you can see, I have to repeat this code 7 times for every day of the week, using switch case every single time just so I can get the exercises to go to their right links. I feel like this is a terrible and inefficient way to do this, but I don't know/can't think of better ways, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: `<li>` is invalid child of `<a>` . The `<a>` should be child of the `<li>`

Comment: Ahhhhhh, thank you for that tip

Comment: make a function?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in ejs or if I make it outside it I'm not sure how to get it to include the links

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to use objects. You can call an object like `foo.bar` or `foo['bar']`.
So start by creating an object like:

```
const exercices = {
'Hanging leg raise': <a href="/muscles/abs/hanginglegraise"><li></a>
// Fill with the rest
...
}

routine.monday.forEach(monday => { %>
    <ul>
exercices[monday.exercice]
</ul>
} %>
```

Use this design pattern has a base for what you need.

Or

```
routine.monday.forEach(monday => { %>
    <ul>
      <a href=`/muscles/abs/${monday.exercice.trim()}`><li><%= monday.exercise %></li></a>
    </ul>
} %>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to create a const like you just did in ejs, and if I try to do it in javascript, it gives me an error because I'm trying to use html in javascript.

Comment: Also, doesn't trim only remove the whitespace from both ends of the string? So it wouldn't remove the spaces in between the words?

Comment: @ChanKim: the point is, find a way to derive that link from `exercise`, because that's the only variable part between your switch arms. For example, store it in the database. Your sample array shows you're storing both id and name, but you're not using id. Do the other way around: drop the name, store only id. When rendering a page, fetch all exercises (which would be their own documents in their own collection) by id and read the links from them.

Comment: @ChanKim Yes you are right the trim does not remove the whitespace in between I forgot that for a second. The best way to what you want is like @SergioTulentsev said, only rely on the id. You add that logic outside of the ejs part, you can pass data to your ejs file like `res.render('index',{exercise: monday.exercise});` and on your .ejs file you call `<%=exercise%>`.

Comment: Okay, I feel very stupid right now but I don't quite understand, sorry haha. You guys are saying I should get rid of the "exercise" field from the database and replace it with something like "link" for example, which would be the link for the page rather than the name of the exercise, right? Sorry, I'm not following that well